# How do I fix no module found error in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the Django docs and I'm going through the first project called **"mysite"** and it has an app called **polls**

**This is my file structure :**

```
\pythonproject
  \mysite
      \mysite
      \polls
          \migrations
           __init.py__
           admin.py
           apps.py
           models.py
           tests.py
           urls.py
           views.py   
   __init__.py   
   db.sqlite3
   manage.py
```

I am in this location : **polls\urls.py** and I want to import **"polls\views.py"**

So I type in this :

```
from mysite.polls import views
```

And I get the error when I ran:

```
python manage.py test
```

This is the error :

```
No module found "mysite.polls"
```

**The error refers to the second line of code in polls\urls.py**

I am using **pycharm** and my **Django version is "3.2.8"**
My **python version is "3.10"**

Answer (score 0):

If polls is your app name then just importing views from polls app might do the thing.

`from polls import views`

or if you are working under the same app directory just use

```
from . import views
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: **from polls import views** returned this error : **No module found "polls"**   and **from . import views** returned this error :  **attempted relative import with no known parent package**

Comment: did u include app on settings.py??
if not, then add your app "polls" in the Installed_apps in settings.py